# Read from a certain point to a certain character

Tags: bash, string

Say I have a file like this:

```
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar something useful"foo bar foo bar"
```

Basically, I want to know how I can get the string `something useful` by itself, either saved to its own file or displayed as output alone.

There will always be the same number of characters (33) before `something useful` and there will always be `"` directly after it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
cut -c 34- | cut -d '"' -f1
```

First `cut` removes the first 33 characters; second `cut` keeps only the part before the first `"`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is GNU `grep` version using perl syntax:

```
grep -oP '.{32}\K[^"]*'
```

it greps first 32 characters, cuts it away with `\K` and prints the rest until first `"`.

Answer (score 3):

In bash and parameter expansion expression

```bsh
$ nline="${line%%\"*}" #strip everything from first " seen to the end
$ echo "${nline:32}"   #print everything from offset 32 to the end
```

Answer (score 2):

A vim solution:

```
vim test.txt -c '%s/\v.{32}(.{-})".*/\1' -c 'w output.txt' -c 'q!'
```

Saves the result in `output.txt`, which obviously could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to achieve your task

```
sed -e 's/^.\{32\}//;s/".*//' filename.txt
```

This removes the first 32 characters and removes everything after the first `"`.

These substitutions will occur on every line of the file. To apply this to a specific line, use this:

```
sed -e 'linenumber{s/^.\{32\}//;s/".*//;}' filename.txt
```

where `linenumber` is any number.

```
linenumber{          # on the linenumber-th line, do the following
 s/^.\{32\}//        #  remove the first 33 characters
 s/".*//             #  remove the first quote and everything following it
}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for spotting my mistake, I always mix up `//` with line numbers.